# Type trait to identify types that can be read/written in binary form

Tags: c++, c++11, binaryfiles, traits

Is there a type trait (or concept) to identify those types for which the following is safe?

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::some_type_trait<T>::value> Write(std::ostream &os,const T &x)
  { os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&x),sizeof(T)); }

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::some_type_trait<T>::value> Read(std::istream &is,T &x)
  { is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&x),sizeof(T)); }
```

I’m thinking of classes containing POD excluding pointers (but not arrays). Something like `StandardLayoutType`s but without pointers. I neither want to constrain the objects to be `TrivialType` nor `TriviallyCopyable`.

Sorry if I’m inaccurate. I know very little of data representation.

Comment: erm: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod

Comment: @Nim Thanks. The problem is that `struct T { int i; double *p; };` is POD. and I want to exclude types with pointer members.

Comment: @Nim `is_pod` also requires the type to be trivial.

Comment: @metalfox I think you'd need static reflection or compiler support for something as introspective as that.

Comment: The compiler can't know whether `i` in `struct S{ int i; };`  is really an index into a global array, say. In that case only part of the value is stored by storing the direct instance data. So  you will have to specialize such a trait for each relevant type.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf This is what I do currently. I hoped it could be expressed as a conjuntion of built-in type traits.

Comment: Nonportable issues: endianness, `sizeof(int)` etc., struct alignment. There might be applications where you know this isn't and will not be a problem ever - but it's not suitable for a general serialization mechanism. use a standardized text-based store (such as JSON), or normalize your binary data to something that you can still read safely read tomorrow. Or use something that does that for you (e.g. SQLite -  https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

Comment: @peterchen I know of these portability limitations. Yet my pograms are for personal use only. In practice, I never experienced those problems by specialization of a trait. Anyway, that's an important remark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a 1<sup>st</sup> parameter of `s`, the [`read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) method:

> Extracts characters and stores them into successive locations of the character array whose first element is pointed to by `s`

So your real question is: **If I have initialized an object by writing a string of bytes to it's address, is it valid?**

This is the concept of [Value Representation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Object_representation_and_value_representation). And the value representation of [*Trivially Copyable*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable) types is such that:

> Copying the bytes occupied by the object in the storage is sufficient to produce another object with the same value

Thus you want to ensure that your object is *Trivially Copyable* this isn't per say a standard concept but it can be succinctly defined as:

> - Every [copy constructor is *Trivial*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Trivial_copy_constructor) or deleted
> - Every [move constructor is *Trivial*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Trivial_move_constructor) or deleted
> - Every [copy assignment operator is *Trivial*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator#Trivial_copy_assignment_operator) or deleted
> - Every [move assignment operator is *Trivial*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_operator#Trivial_move_assignment_operator) or deleted
> - At least one copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator is non-deleted
> - [*Trivial* non-deleted destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Trivial_destructor)

The spirit of the assertion that at least one *Trivial* initializer exists for the object boils down to these requirements of a *Trivially Copyable* type, it's non-static members, and any of it's base classes:

1. It's given *Trivial* Initializer is, or behaves as, the corresponding default intializer
2. It has no virtual methods
3. It has no members of a volatile-qualified type

As far as the requirement of a *Trivial* destructor:

> - The destructor is not user-provided (meaning, it is either implicitly declared, or explicitly defined as defaulted on its first declaration)
> - The destructor is not virtual (that is, the base class destructor is not virtual)
> - All direct base classes have trivial destructors
> - All non-static data members of class type (or array of class type) have trivial destructors

---

Having fully defined what it means to be a *Trivially Copyable* type, it is impossible for a "type trait or concept" to determine whether all of these requirements are met in all cases, for example: A type that defines a *Trivial* Initializer with a signature that matches the default initializer may or may not be *Trivially Copyable* contingent on the code which initializes the type in that initializers body; For such a type, the only way to determine if it's *Trivially Copyable* is human inspection of the initializer. If however you are willing to tighten the requirements to what *is* detectable, [`is_trivially_copyable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) will guarantee that your type is *Trivially Copyable*.

Comment: How about [`is_trivially_copyable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable)?  This is a little less restrictive than `is_trivial`.  In the notes it even mentions that types that match this are the only types that can be (de)serialized and `memcpy`'d safely.

Comment: @GuyGreer `is_trivially_copyable` does not impose the requirement that the destructor is defaulted, thus it does not ensure a *Trivially Copyable* type. (I had considered suggesting that as well as `is_pod` though.)

Comment: Why does it matter what the destructor does here?

Comment: @GuyGreer A non default destructor is used to clean up state or memory external to the object itself. The existence of such a destructor is indicative that the internal state of the object could only be reached by altering external memory or state. I will say that I've never seen a class with a trivial copy-constructor which had a non-*Trivial* destructor.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks. I don't really understand why writting a pointer value (i.e. a memory address) to a file is considered "safe" though. I think that the "academic" concept of safety does not model my needs.

Comment: @metalfox How would you normally initialize that pointer in your copy constructor?  If it's via defining the copy constructor yourself then the class is no longer trivially copy-constructible.  Similarly for the move constructor, assignment operator and move-assignment operator.

Comment: @metalfox Let's stop and think through how that would happen. Who is responsible for the cleanup of that pointer? If it is owned by the object, then the object needs a destructor to clean it up, making it a non-*Trivially Copyable* type. If the pointer is owned externally, then the use of said pointer would need to be gated anyway by a validation that the externally owned value is still valid. In practice a raw pointer to an externally owned object is a bad idea. C++ provides so many better tools for handling this like `weak_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @JonathanMee @GuyGreer Imagine a `struct` with an "observer_ptr". I don't consider it appropriate for the functions above. IMO, it is also unfortunate that simple structures (layout-wise) such as `struct T { int i; double d; T(const &x): i(x.i) {} };` won't be "writeable".

Comment: @metalfox Are you referring to this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr That has all the same issues a raw pointer does as described above. I'm not certain why you're saying `struct T` is not writable, it meets the requirements of *Trivially Copyable*. Though I am assuming `const &x` was supposed to be something that would compile.

Comment: @JonathanMee I was referring to a pointer without any degree of ownership, generically. Sorry, there was a typo. It was supposed to be a copy constructor `T(const T &x): i(x.i) {}`

Comment: @metalfox For that copy constructor, I would say that it's bad practise to write a constructor that does the exact same thing that the default constructor would do for you, especially since you could get out of sync with the class if you added a new member but forgot to add it to the initialization list of the copy constructor.

Comment: @metalfox I'm still not sure what we're talking about here `T(const T& x) : i(x.i) {}` does not initialize `d` so it is not a *Trivial* copy-constructor therefore this would not be a *Trivially Copyable* object... Are you asking something about that? There's no such thing as a pointer to a valid object with no ownership. Something owns that object. I'm thinking perhaps it would be helpful to open a new question(s) and link them here. I think I'm just having a hard time understanding your questions because of the limited expression in comments.

Comment: @JonathanMee It's not necessary. The question is perfectly solved. Thanks

Comment: What on earth does `is_trivially_copyable<T>` tell you, if it's not whether `T` is trivially copyable? The first part is fine modulo the silly caps. The second part is complete nonsense.

Comment: @T.C. Ugh... You're right. I just reread `is_trivially_copyable` in the cold light of day, that is correct. I misunderstood it on my first pass; I've edited. You're probably correct on whatever else you're saying as well, but I'm not getting it: "silly caps" "second part"?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not.

If we had full reflection (coming to a C++ standard near you by <s>2014</s> <s>2017</s> 2020!) you could write your own trait to some extent.

But even there you run into a problem.

A `std::size_t` could be a value, or an index into some hash table of `const char*`s seeded by their memory location.  Such a value is *not* safe to write out, then read again on the next execution of the program.

On top of that, the reading code could disagree how big a `int` is.  So now you have to distinguish between `int32_t` and `int`, both of which are permitted to be the same type on compiler 1 yet different types on compiler 2 (or even compiler settings!).

Your best bet is to use your own type trait of Koenig flag-function that claims something is safe to binary serialize, with some overridable safety checks (generate errors if the type is no longer pod, standard layout, trivially copyable, etc).

Beyond that, you should consider using an archive system instead.  Add reflection that lets you read/write the state of the object.  Make aggregage objects easy to recurse on.

```
template<class Stream>
void Archive( Stream& s ) {
  s.start(*this)->*[&]{
    s & field1;
    s & field2;
    s & field3;
  };
}
```

where this code splits into a reader or a writer engine depending on the type of `Stream`, encodes a header and (optionally) a type flag of some kind for `*this` and a length.  It then streams the content in/out.  Extra stuff at the end is automatically discarded.

For binary types:

```
template<class Stream>
void Archive( Stream& s ) {
  FlatBinary( *this, s );
}
```

does all that for you, but still ensures that sizes align and the like (permiting the structure to grow in later revisions without breaking things!)  We can even detect flat binary types and not have to implement `Archive` via a flag.

Put:

```
friend std::true_type is_flat_binary_test( BobType ) { return {}; }
```

in such types.  Then do a

```
namespace flat_binary_details {
  template<class T>
  inline std::false_type is_flat_binary_test( T ) { return {}; }

  template<class T>
  inline auto flat_binary_f()
  -> decltype( is_flat_binary_test( std::declval<T>() ) )
  { return {}; }
}
template<class T>
using is_flat_binary = decltype( details::flag_binary_f<T>() );
```

Now, `is_flat_binary< std::vector<int> >` is `false_type`, while

```
namespace X {
  struct Bob {
    friend std::true_type is_flat_binary_test( Bob ); // body optional
  };
}
static_assert( is_flat_binary<X::Bob>{}, "Bob is flat!" );
```

just works.

Your archive system can test for things flagged as flat binary, and implement an efficient archive system for them.  Ones without it it can detect the `Archive( Stream& )` member and invoke it.  Ones without that it can detect `Read` and `Write`.  Non-default constructible types can be extended.  Non-member `Achive` for `std` types can be written.

But that is getting too far.  In short, archiving stuff is hard, find a framework.

Comment: _"If we had full reflection (coming to a C++ standard near you by 2014 2017 2020!)"_ What do you mean? AFAIK, full reflection is not possible without compiler's help (e.g `std::is_member_private<>`). Perhaps there's some paper accounting that?

Comment: @black There are, and continue to be, reflection proposals for C++.  There is a working group.  I would say C++20, but I'm cynical; hence the crossed out 2014 and 2017 to incidate that 2020 is not guaranteed.

Comment: I see, thanks. It's quite hard indeed: the first and foremost thing to define would be reflection term itself. The way dynamic languages like Java or C# reflect themselves can't be the same for C++, of course, due to the nature of the language. And agreeing on what might be useful or not is, indeed, time-consuming. Let alone finding an interface.

Comment: @black the plan is compile-time only reflection.  If you want run time reflection, you implement it using compile-time reflection as you see fit.  With reification being a separate problem.  This eliminates the run-time cost, except for when you choose to use it, and ensures backward compatibility.  The last proposal I read had it being an operator (like `decltype`) that took a variety of language constructs (including namespaces and types) and returned a type with properties that described the thing you fed the operator; grist for a library, not a complete solution.